# Running a cron job on Linux every six hours

Tags: linux, cron

How can I run command every six hours every day?

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
/6 * * * * *  mycommand
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run crontab for every 2 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423532/how-to-run-crontab-for-every-2-hours)

Comment: how about * */6 * * *

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You forgot a `*`, and you've too many fields. It's the hour you need to care about

```
0 */6 * * * /path/to/mycommand
```

This means every sixth hour starting from 0, i.e. at hour 0, 6, 12 and 18 which you could write as

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * /path/to/mycommand
```

Comment: thank your for the response, this is every 6 hours starting what time? the time when the cron is created?

Comment: thanks, so if I wanted to run it starting from 15:00 every 6 hours it would be `15 15,23,05,11 * * * /path/to/mycommand` ?

Comment: Yes, though the first field is the minute, which you've set to 15, so that'll mean 15:15,23:15,05:15 and 11:15. (which isn't every 6th hour btw, you might have meant `0 15,21,3,9 * * *`)

Answer (score 7):

You should include a path to your command, since cron runs with an extensively cut-down environment. You won't have all the environment variables you have in your interactive shell session.

It's a good idea to specify an absolute path to your script/binary, or define PATH in the crontab itself. To help debug any issues I would also redirect stdout/err to a log file.

Comment: thanks for the response, but if I declare environment variables inside my sh file like `export variable=something` I get to still use them inside that same script? and I use date command alot inside the script

Comment: @Gandalf - Yes. You can define all your env variables inside the script. That's a good idea since it means your script is standalone and isolated from other stuff you may want to run within cron

Answer (score 7):

**Please keep attention at this syntax**:

```
* */6 * * *
```

This means 60 *times* (every minute) every 6 hours,

**not**

one time every 6 hours.

Answer (score 5):

```
0 */6 * * * command
```

This will be the perfect way to say 6 hours a day.

Your command puts in for six minutes!

Comment: @ArsenArsen I am pretty sure it was because it doesn't really add anything to the existing accepted answer, wrote 4 years before it.

Answer (score 2):

nice website for this purpose :)

https://cron.help/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
0 */6 * * *
```

crontab every 6 hours is a commonly used cron schedule.

Comment: What does this answer add that the other answers don't? @rkoots has already mentioned this exact command.

Comment: *"Commonly used"*? Why? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -4):

Try:

```
0 */6 * * * command
```

. * has to

Comment: The last line here doesn't make much sense. Would you consider expanding it?

Comment: looks like the answer is incomplete