# How can I run command every twelve hours every day? Tried this not working : /12 * * * * * mycommand

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How can I run command every twelve hours every day? Tried this not working :

```
  /12 * * * * *  mycommand
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11562834/2235132) and replace 6 by 12!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0 0,12 * * * yourcommand
```

executes your command at 0 and at 12 o'clock.

```
*/12 * * * *  your command
```

would execute your command every 12 minutes each hour.

Comment: +1. An alternative to your first line would be `0 0/12 * * *`, using the `/12` syntax used by the OP.