# Cron expressions do not run at the expected times

Tags: cron

Now it's 3/12/2018  3:02:13 PM.

I have a cron expression `0 0 0/7 * * ?` (every 7 hours starting at 00 am, of every day). As a result, executions:

```
 1. 3/12/2018 9:00 PM
 2. 3/13/2018 12:00 AM
 3. 3/13/2018 7:00 AM
 4. 3/13/2018 2:00 PM
 5. 3/13/2018 9:00 PM
 6. 3/14/2018 12:00 AM
 7. 3/14/2018 7:00 AM
```

As you can see, there were 3 hours between 1st, 2nd and 5th, 6th runs. Not 7.

Is it possible to make the rules run at the correct time, like this?

```
 1. 3/12/2018 9:00 PM
 2. 3/13/2018 4:00 AM
 3. 3/13/2018 11:00 AM
 4. 3/13/2018 6:00 PM
```

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Title is not in english.

Comment: Title aside, what's this got to do with Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running cron job on linux every 6 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562804/running-cron-job-on-linux-every-6-hours)

Comment: This cron does what you told it to: starting from 0:00 every seven hours (which *will* have jumps, because 24 is not a multiple of 7).

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting "every 7 hours starting at 00 am" - you are starting in intervals of 7. I think. You should have a look at the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto or the examples at http://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions